# Can I migrate my Time Machine from HFS+ to a new drive with APFS?

Tags: time-machine, apfs, hfs+

I am running Big Sur 11.5.2

I bought a new drive (2 x 4TB RAID1 Array) to use in place of my existing 4TB Time Machine drive.  Both are USB.  I want to migrate my old Time Machine which is HFS+ to the new drive which I would like to be APFS.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so as the way time machine works I think differs between HFS and APFS. The latter uses snapshots which arn'e provided by HFS.